# Take a number to queue in a supermarket

Tags: ruby, variables

Assuming that we are in a supermarket, where every time people enter, they take a number to queue. I need to:

- Increment a counter by 1 for each person that takes the number,
- Place the counter into the array to represent the person who just entered (to let them know what's their position in the queue),
- Return the total number of people who came that day until the moment that the method was called.

This is my code:

```
def take_a_number(array)
  counter = 0
  counter += 1
  array << counter
  counter
end
```

Every time I call this method, it will bring the counter down to zero. How could I avoid that, and retain the total number of people?

Comment: Welcome to SO! While your story is compelling, I recommend removing that in the interest of keeping focus on your question. Also, your code has a stray backtick, making it invalid. I recommend refining your question a bit.

Comment: The array should tell the position. And can be empty. Define variables outside the method (scope).

Answer (score 0):

You should declare counter as 0 outside the method definition

Answer (score 0):

It probably would be better to store this in a instance variable of a class. But not having more context, but basically you have your information in the array, you should look what the last counter was set to:

```
def take_a_number(array)
  if array.empty?
    counter = 1
  else
    counter = array.last + 1
  end
  array << counter
  counter
end
```

You can shorten this statement to this:

```
 def take_a_number(array)
   counter = array.empty? ? 1 : array.last + 1
   array << counter
   counter
 end
```

Another way, would be to just look at the lenght of the array:

```
 def take_a_number(array)
   counter = array.length + 1 
   array << counter
   counter
 end
```

Or you can even write this shorter:

```
def take_a_number(array)
  array << array.length+1
  array.length
end
```

But as I said at the start it would be better to pack all this together into a model, then you can use instance variables

```
class Queue
  def initialize
    @list = []
    @current_number = 0
  end

  def take_a_number
    @current_number += 1
    @list << @current_number
    @current_number
  end

  def take_turn
    @list.shift
  end
end

waiting_line_1 = Queue.new    #get a new queue, you could have multiple ones...

waiting_line_1.take_a_number  #first person takes a number
waiting_line_1.take_a_number  #second person takes a number

waiting_line_1.take_turn      #first person takes a turn / is called
```